# Function with arguements and creating variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments

I'm completely new to coding and I'm trying to create a function that will request user inputs, store the inputs in a variable to be created on the fly, and in the end output the conversion of the variable; my code is right below. Thanks:

```js
function dogHuman(yes, no) {
  var humanAge = ((dogAge - 2) * 4) + 21;
  var haveDog = prompt("Do you have a dog? " + "yes" + " or " + "no");

  if (haveDog == yes) {
    var dogAge = prompt("How old is your dog? ");
    alert("If your dog were human, it would be " + humanAge + " years old");
  } else if (haveDog == no) {
    alert("Thank you for you attention");
  } else {
    var haveDog = prompt("Do you have a dog? " + "yes" + " or " + "no" + yes + no);
  }
}

dogHuman();
```

Comment: Where is your `dogAge` variable coming from? Also, you need to pass in your parameters in the function call at the end. I think these were meant to NOT be strings in your concatenation as well.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl From `var dogAge = prompt("How old is your dog? ");` apparently

Comment: "*Function with arguements*" - what did you mean to pass as arguments? What are the two parameters supposed to do?

Comment: @Bergi They are using `dogAge` on the first line of the function, before it is set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems,

1. Pass the appropriate parameters into the function call.
2. Move the `humanAge` assignment after the `dogAge` prompt, because that needs to happen first.
3. Make sure not to quote your variables

```js
function dogHuman(yes, no) {
  var haveDog = prompt("Do you have a dog? " + yes + " or " + no);

  if (haveDog === yes) {
    var dogAge = prompt("How old is your dog? ");
    var humanAge = ((dogAge - 2) * 4) + 21;
    alert("If your dog were human, it would be " + humanAge + " years old");
    dogHuman(yes, no); // Recursion
  } else {
    alert("Thank you for you attention");
  }
}

dogHuman('yes', 'no'); // Pass your parameters into the call
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is with `haveDog == yes` & `haveDog == no`. Here `yes` & `no` are string. So have to compare like `'haveDog === 'yes'`. No use of `===`. Secondly calculate `humanAge` only if the user types `yes` otherwise it will `undefined`

```js
function dogHuman(yes, no) {
  var haveDog = prompt("Do you have a dog? " + "yes" + " or " + "no");
  if (haveDog === 'yes') {
    var dogAge = prompt("How old is your dog? ");
    var humanAge = ((dogAge - 2) * 4) + 21;
    alert("If your dog were human, it would be " + humanAge + " years old");
  } else {
    alert("Thank you for you attention");
  }

}

dogHuman();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is, so instead I'll just go over everything I notice:

1. `dogHuman` is called without any arguments, and looking at your code, it probably shouldn't have any arguments.
2. Javascript (as, indeed, most languages) does things in order, so `var humanAge = ((dogAge - 2) * 4) + 21;` should go after `dogAge` is first determined.
3. Since `haveDog` is taking a `prompt`, you probably want to compare `haveDog` to `"yes"` rather than just `yes`.
4. `"Do you have a dog? " + "yes" + " or " + "no"` can be rewritten as just `"Do you have a dog? yes or no"`

Variables are set once; they don't rerun what you set them to every time you run them; this misconception is common, and is where I think the early `humanAge` definition is coming from.